# Align label to the middle of dock panel

Tags: wpf

I have a dock panel, with one label in the middle and another button on the far right.

Because of the button the label cannot align to the middle when the windows is maximized.

WPF:

```
<DockPanel Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1,-2,0,0" Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" OpacityMask="{x:Null}">
            <Label FontSize="18" Content="Sales" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" Width="883" Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></Label>
            <Button FontSize="18" Height="47" Width="123" Name="btnStart" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT" ClickMode="Press" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Content="Start" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False">
        </DockPanel>
```

Comment: DockPanel is not the right container for this

Comment: have you tried making a three column grid and putting the label in the middle of the middle column, and the button at the right of the right column?

Comment: i like your solution paul. Obviously DockPanel is not right control for this but that is not the right answer. It may not be an option to replace it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a `Grid` instead of a `DockPanel`

Grid's allow objects to be placed on top of each other, so you can position your Label in the middle and the Button on the Right

```
<Grid>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```

Also if you're new to WPF's Layouts, I'd recommend reading through [WPF Layouts: A Quick Visual Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start) so you know what layouts are available and can pick the best one for your sitaution